# Rewrite URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've this url: http://www.test.com/page.php?k=m1ns

and I want this one: http://www.test.com/r/m1ns

My .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^k/([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?k=$1 [L]

# force www. in all requests
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# enable hiding php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

But it doesn't work. Only the non-www -> www and hiding php rules works.
If I put http://www.test.com/page.php?k=m1ns does not rewrite.

Anyone knows why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^r/([^/]*)$ /page.php?k=$1 [L]
```

On your top page.php

```
if (strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/page.php?k=' . $var . '')) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("location:http://www.test.com/r/" . $var );
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^r/(.*)/ /page.php?k=$1 [L]
```

It should work regardless of whether or not www is entered.

Comment: I've uploaded .htaccess on my ftp and tried to load "http://www.test.com/page.php?k=29ms" but the url is not rewrited.

Comment: Go to test.com/r/29ms and your script will view it the same as test.com/page.php?k=29ms