# PHP remove extension & rewrite $_GET request

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm trying to rewrite PHP URLs from:
example.org/file.php?param=val&param=val

to:
example.org/file/param/val/param/val

With every PHP file on my server, but I can't figure it out. My .htaccess will remove the .php extension, but I can't get it to rewrite $_GET requests.

If somebody can help me out that'd be great. Also, I plan on using nginx for production, so I'd appreciate it if somebody can help me convert the .htaccess to be compatible with nginx.

Thanks!

Edit:
This is my current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rewrite URL with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527628/rewrite-url-with-htaccess)

Comment: http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/

Comment: @Machavity I want to do this with ALL php files on my server, not just a single specificed one.

Comment: @Parker That is way too complex for what I'm trying to to.

Answer (score 0):

No direct experience with it, but [this page](http://statichtml.com/2010/mod-rewrite-baseon-on-query-string.html) indicates you want to use a `RewriteCond` to look for the query string, and apply a regex matching pattern to the same.  That pattern's matchs will then be available in your rewrite rule.

So, if I understand that correctly, the following

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^query=(.*)$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^/old-search$       /search/(%1)    [NC,L,R=301]
```

Would match a url like

```
/old-search?query=something
```

and turn it into

```
/search/something
```

Syntax will probably vary depending on Apache version.