# Redirect page rewrite to transform with htaccess php mode rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to use mod_rewrite to transform:

```
/anneevideo.php?annee=2015&page=1&sort=m.title&direction=asc
```

to

```
/video-produit-en-2015?page=1&sort=m.title&direction=asc
```

AND

```
/anneevideo.php?annee=2015&page=1
```

to

```
/video-produit-en-2015?page=1
```

AND

```
/anneevideo.php?annee=2015
```

to

```
/video-produit-en-2015
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527628/rewrite-url-with-htaccess

Comment: not the same , i would add ? in url